# Make list to be field of the class, not of the method

Tags: optimization, groovy

```
def list = ['one', 'two']
```

This script will be compiled by Groovy to something like this:

```
class script extends Script {
    ...
    public Object run() {
        ...
        List list = ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createList(new Object[]{"one", "two"});
        ...
    }
}
```

Can I move out defined `list` to class field so list will not be created again on each `run` call? Write full class instead of script is not an option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`@Field` annotation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html)

```
@Field def list = ['one', 'two']
```

Comment: Dang you clever developer you @tim_yates

Comment: @tim_yates, is it possible to annotate list as an argument on method call for brevity: `method([1, 2, 3])`?

Comment: @cybersoft not sure I get you

Comment: If you mean _"can I annotate a constant I'm passing to a method so that it automatically becomes a class field with some name "_ then the answer is no

Comment: @tim_yates yes, I meant this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries glad to help! Groovy can save you a lot of boilerplate code, but even it can't save you from having to name your fields ;-)  have fun!